Increasing the absolute maximum size of a `Circle`?
Consider the Grouped Points with Proportional Symbols Map example: here circles are plotted so that their size (specifically, their area) is proportional to the data: in this case, the number of airports.
The legend shows how the size of the circle corresponds to the count of airports.
Is it possible to increase the absolute (not relative to other data; so Size/Scale as explained in this answer is not relevant) area of the circle that corresponds to the maximum value? Suppose that the radius of the circle corresponding to the maximum value is 1.0 em. Can I make it 2 em large?

You can do something like alt.Size('column').scale(range=(0, 1000)) as in this example  https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/airport_connections.html

I don't think that increases the absolute size of the largest circle? That only makes it so that the largest circle is associated with value 1000. I want to change how large the largest circle is (e.g. make it 200 pixels instead of 50 pixels).

@bzm3r range does change the absolute size of the circles. You can see that the biggest points in the example I linked are larger than in the airport example you linked in your question (you should also see this if you run that code and play around with the range values.  What you are describing in your comment is the domain parameter, which sets which data value should be mapped/associated to the largest and smallest circle size.
